# $urlRouterprovider.otherwise page always shows before navigating

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a default state defined like `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');` which should redirect me to the login page if the inserted url doesn't exists, but I always see the login page(for a split of a second) before seen the page I'm really navigating too(which means the requested url exists...)... any ideas of why of this behaviour can be happening?

Comment: Could you possibly replicate this on a plunkr?

Comment: Agree with @SatejS. More info is needed.

Comment: I doubt I could replicate the problem, is the first time I see this behaviour, also not in liberty to share the code, so just wondering if someone else have had similar issue

Comment: This is currently a bit too broad of a question. Could you please provide more context or clues? Maybe what you have tried?

Comment: I've tried removing the otherwise condition and navigation works(except if I enter a wrong url), when I put it back navigation keeps working but it shows the otherwise page for a split of a second. I also capture the event $locationChangeSuccess and I can see that everytime I navigate between pages this method gets called 3 times when there is no otherwise clause and 4 times when there is otherwise condition, first 2 times with just localhost:portNumber/ ...